# Why can't I replace an existing table in my MySQL database using the following code?

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas, mysql-connector

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_instrumentos = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Market','Ticker','cficode'))
db_instrumentos = db_instrumentos.append({'Market':'NYSE'],
            'Ticker':'MMM',
            'cficode':'EAEWD25A'},
            ignore_index=True)
 
db = db_obtenerInstrumentos

sql_engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost')
sql_conn = sql_engine.connect()
sql_conn.execute(f"CREATE database IF NOT EXISTS proof_Rofex")
sql_conn.execute(f"USE proof_Rofex")

db.to_sql(con=sql_conn, name='proof_table2', if_exists="replace")

sql_conn.close()
```

I am wanting to use this line of code db.to_sql (with = sql_conn, name = 'proof_table2', if_exists = "replace") and it throws me the following error

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1050, "Table 'proof_table2' already exists") [SQL: CREATE TABLE proof_table2 (index BIGINT, Market TEXT, Ticker TEXT, cficode TEXT)

] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

the proof_table2 table already exists but precisely that line should allow me to make a drop and replace ... that error that throws me is precisely on that line

Comment: Does your account have DELETE permissions on this table? Check General Log - does DROP TABLE is sent to MySQL?

Comment: All users have all permissions on this table. User: root Server127.0.0.1,User: root Server: localhost, User: root Server: ::1

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by adding schema, for your example it should be as below:

```
db.to_sql(con=sql_conn, name='proof_table2', if_exists='replace', 
schema='proof_Rofex')
```